# continue command ignores breakpoints

Tags: perl, perldb

I'm getting errors using CPAN and, as output is rather unhelpful, resorted to debugging this.

```
$ perl -d /usr/bin/cpan CPAN

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
<...>
main::(/usr/bin/cpan:2):            eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
main::(/usr/bin/cpan:3):                if $running_under_some_shell;
  DB<1> b /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/HTTP/Tiny.pm:125
  DB<2> L
/usr/bin/cpan:
 2:         eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   break if (/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/HTTP/Tiny.pm:125)
  DB<2> c
```

After `c`, the program runs to completion, ignoring the breakpoint.

`/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/HTTP/Tiny.pm:125` is the following line, outside any conditional blocks.

```
my $request = {
    method    => $method,
    scheme    => $scheme,
    host_port => ($port == $DefaultPort{$scheme} ? $host : "$host:$port"),
    uri       => $path_query,
    headers   => {},
};
```

Setting a break on line 142 (that's causing errors that I'm debugging) makes no difference.

From the `L` output, it looks like the breakpoint is set on the current line rather than the one I need. But, [`perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) lists `b file:line` as valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax might be a newer addition, I wasn't able to get it working here either. I have 5.8.8 on Unix and 5.10.1 on Windows and both don't seem to work. I get the breakpoint on my current line as you do (it treats the whole string as a condition).

I'd suggest using another syntax as below.

**Break on the method:**

```
b HTTP::Tiny::some_method
```

**Select the file, break on the line (it matches on paths, not module namespaces):**

```
f HTTP/Tiny
b 125
```

If they are loaded at runtime with require or eval, the debugger won't know about the module yet so you can just type `use HTTP::Tiny` in the debugger first to force it to load.

Comment: Indeed, blaming `perldebug.pod` in Perl Git repo shows this was added in `076b743fc5f369c78306040642d57f05f84f6dba` on 2011-06-16. The next commit adds the corresponding notice into `perldelta.pod`, searching which in the current codebase reveals this was added in `5.16.0`.